# Redis : Is there a limit to the number of keys that i can store?

Tags: redis, jedis

First the context, im trying to use Redis as an in-memory store backed with persistence. I need to store large number of objects (millions) in a Redis Hash.

At the same time, i don't want my redis instance to consume too much memory. So i've set the *maxmemory* property in redis.conf to 100mb. I've set *maxmemory-policy* as *allkeys-random* The persistece mode is AOF and fysnc is every second.

Now the issue iam facing is, every time i try to store more than two hundred thousand ojects in the hash, the hash gets reset (ie all the existing key values in the hash vanishes ). I confirm this by using the hlen command on the hash in the redis-cli.

Find below the object im trying to store

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int id;
String name;
String department;
String address;

    /* Getters and Setters */

    /* Hashcode - Generates hashcode (key) for each object */
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((department == null) ? 0 : department.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
}
```

Also, Find below the code that stores into redis (Im using Jedis to interact with Redis )

```
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");
    Jedis jedis = (Jedis) jedisPool.getResource();

    System.out.println("Starting....");
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {

             /* Converting object to byte array */
        Employee employee = new Employee(i, "Arun Jolly", "IT", "SomeCompany");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(employee);
        byte[] value = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        /* Creating key in byte array format using hashCode() */
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
        buffer.putInt(employee.hashCode());
        byte[] field = buffer.array();

            /* Specyfying the Redis Hash in byte array format */ 
        String tableName = "Employee_Details";
        byte[] key = tableName.getBytes();

        jedis.hset(key, field, value);
        System.out.println("Stored Employee "+i);
    }
```

Am i missing something ?

Does this mean that redis does not swap out to the disk once the maxmemory is reached ( Is it trying to hold all the key values in memory ? ) Does it mean that i have to incrementally increase the maxmemory limit according to the increase in the number of key-value pairs that i might have to store ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes. Redis is a pure in-memory store, with persistency options. Everything must fit in memory.

> Does this mean that redis does not swap out to the disk once the maxmemory is reached.

Precisely.

> Is it trying to hold all the key values in memory?

Keys and values, yes.

> Does it mean that I have to incrementally increase the max memory limit according to the increase in the number of key-value pairs that I might have to store?

You need to decide upfront how much memory you allocate to Redis, yes.

If you are memory constrained, you will be better served with a disk-based store.

Comment: So this is a scalability issue with redis right ? Does this mean that redis is not intended to be used as a primary data store ? ( Sorry to be asking the same question in a different way...but i need to be absolutely certain before i take a decision on this ). Can you suggest another nosql db which doesn't have these limitations ? (something that can be used as a primary datastore

Comment: It is not a scalability issue, it is a deliberate choice to support only in-memory databases, targeting optimal performance. Disk I/Os are too slow. Redis can be used as a primary data store, provided you have enough memory. If your volume of data does not fit in memory, you may want to have a look at solutions like MongoDB or Couchbase. But do not expect the same kind of raw performance ...

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Comment: I wouldn't use Redis has primary datastore unless you can tolerate 100% data loss.  There's incremental backups available to restore prior state, but you will still experience some data loss.